# Definition and some theorems on separable extensions

Tags: field-theory

> **Theorem 4.3.** Let $E$ be a finite extension of $k$. Then $E$ is separable over $k$ if and only if each element of $E$ is separable
>   over $k$.
>
> **Definition:** Let $E$ be an arbitrary algebraic extension of $k$. We define $E$ to be separable over $k$ if every finitely generated
>   subextension is separable over $k$, i.e. if every extension
>   $k(\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n})$ with $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in E$
>   is separable over $k$.
>
> **Theorem 4.4.** Let $E$ be an algebraic extension of $k$, generated by a family of elements $\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}$. If each $\alpha_i$ is
>   separable over $k$ then $E$ is separable over $k$.
>
> *Proof:* Every element of $E$ lies in some finitely generated subfield $k(\alpha_{i_1},\dots,\alpha_{i_n}),$ and as we remarked above, each
>   such subfield is separable over $k$. Hence every element of $E$ is
>   separable over $k$ by Theorem 4.3, and this concludes the proof.

This is the excerpt from Lang's book and in my opinion the proof of Theorem 4.4 is weird and possibly wrong.

My approach was the following: We have to show that $E$ is separable over $k$. By definition we have to show that each finitely generated subextension is separable over $k$. Take such subextension and call it WLOG $k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$. This is finite extension of $k$ and here we can apply Theorem 4.3. But inorder to get desired result we have to show that each element of this subfield is separable over $k$. 
But can anyone show how to prove this last step?

Would be very grateful for help!

**EDIT:** Let $E$ be an algebraic extension of $k $, possibly infinite extension. If $E$ is separable over $k$. Could we claim that any element $\alpha\in E$ is separable over $k$?

We see that in the case of finite extension this is true (Theorem 4.3.) What about infinite extension?

Comment: I think the main step for (towers of) extensions generated by separable elements is $F = k(\beta), \gamma \in F, L = k(\gamma)$ with $\gamma$ not separable over $k$, let the minimal polynomials $G(x) = \prod_{j=1}^{[L:k]} (x-\gamma_j) \in k[x], G(\gamma)=0,b(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{[F:L]} p_m(\gamma)x^m \in L[x], p_m \in k[t], b(\beta) = 0$ then the coefs of $B(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{[L:k]} (\sum_{m=0}^{[F:L]} p_m(\gamma_j)x^m) $ are symmetric polynomials in the $\gamma_j$ so $B\in k[x]$ and $B(\beta) = 0, \deg(B)=[F:L][L:k]=[F:k]$ so $B$ is $\beta$'s minimal polynomial over $k$ and it is not separable.

Comment: @reuns, which question are you answering?

Comment: @reuns, I am not familiar with symmetric polynomials.

Comment: The latter - edit - and them all, I'm proposing to start with "the coefficients are symmetric polynomials in the $\gamma_j$ implies $B\in k[x]$" from which $\gamma$ non-separable propagates to every elements generating larger extensions. The symmetric polynomials are just saying a polynomial $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is invariant under permutation of the $x_i$ iff it is a polynomial in the coefficients $a_m(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of $\prod_{i=1}^n (Y-x_i)=\sum_{m=0}^n a_m(x_1,\ldots,x_n)Y^m \in R[Y], R = K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Comment: Let me make a comment that I hope you will not take amiss: I’ve seen a sequence of questions from you, all of which begin by you stating that you absolutely understand the preliminary discussions prior to a proof, but that then you get lost. I would suggest that this indicates that you do not, infact, “absolutely understand” the stuff before the proof, because this keeps happening. This is not unusual: it is difficult to tell when one does not in fact understand something that seems clear. For example, that is the role of homework (to verify if you actually understand) (cont)

Comment: (Cont) This is not meant as a put down. I am trying to say that perhaps when you encounter this situation (which you seem to encounter a lot), you should move back a bit and review some of the stuff you think you understood well. Because perhaps you havent. That said, I would also add that Lang is notoriously not the best book to learn some of this stuff for the first time (though I did); it’s great for review, and very encyclopedic, but not particularly easy to digest. You may be better off using some other book in conjunction. (Cont)

Comment: In particular, you might want to check out George Bergman’s [Companion to Lang’s *Algebra*](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/.C.to.L/)

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, thanks a lot for your post! I appreacite your opinion and I am agree. I guess that the reason that Lang's book is not for beginners in field theory and some of the moments of the book I found very weird and difficult and that's why I am asking questions. Maybe i have to read along with Lang's book some other textbook which is written in more easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is same as Lang's proof. You have taken the subfield $k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$. Note that every element of $k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is in $E$ and every element of  $E $ is separable over  $k $ by assumption.
 In particular, every element of $k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is separable over  $k $.Also note that $k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is a finite extension since it is generated by finitely many algebraic elements(you may need to prove this). Now we can  use Theorem 4.3 to conclude that $k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is separable over  $k$, which in turn implies  $E $ is separable over  $k $.

Your second claim is true. If $E$ is an arbitrary extension of $k $ which is separable over  $k $, then $k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is separable over  $k$(defintion) . In particular, if you take any $\alpha\in E $, consider the subfield  $k(\alpha)$ which is separable over  $k$. Note that $k(\alpha) $ is finite since $\alpha$ is algebraic.  Now by Theorem  $4.3$, we can conclude that  $\alpha$ is separable over  $k$.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that we are going from an extension generated by finitely many separatble elements to an extension generated by a possibly infinite collection of separable elements, the $\alpha_i$ with $i\in I$.

So, say that $E$ is generated by the $\alpha_i$. If $a\in E$, then there is a **finite subcollection** of $\alpha_i$s, say $\alpha_{i_1},\ldots,\alpha_{i_n}$, such that $a$ is in fact in $k(\alpha_{i_1},\ldots,\alpha_{i_n})$. Now, since we have already proven that a *finite* extension given by finitely many separable elements has the property that *every* element in the extension is separable, it follows that $a$ is separable over $k$ (when viewed as an element of the finite, finitely generated by separable elements extension $k(\alpha_{i_1},\ldots,\alpha_{i_n})$ over $k$), and so is separable, period.

Thus, every element of $E$ is separable over $k$. Therefore, $E$ is separable over $k$.

What you seem to have missed is that the $\alpha_{i_j}$ in the proof are not arbitrary elements, they are elements taken from the family of generators of the extension that are already known to be each separable.